# HAProxy - Securing inbound TCP connections

Tags: ssl, proxy, http, haproxy, squid

I've been trying to implement a load balanced secured proxy passthrough using HAProxy. Basically what I want to do is this:

```
request ----> haproxy passthrough -----> multiple proxy servers -----> target
```

Now, I didn't want this to just be opened to the public, so I added HTTP Basic auth for the HTTP requests. It's working fine and un-authorized requests are getting denied.

However, I haven't been able to do the same for HTTPS requests, and all of them pass through without any security or limitations.

Please note that using a source ip limitation is not a possibility as the request can come from a variety of sources.

Here is my haproxy.cfg file:

```
global
        log /dev/log   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout     5000
        clitimeout     50000
        srvtimeout     50000

userlist L1
    user john insecure-password doedoe

listen webproxies 0.0.0.0:3128
    bind *:3128
    mode http
    option httplog
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server proxy01 [proxy_ip_1]:[port] check
    server proxy02 [proxy_ip_2]:[port] check
    acl auth_ok http_auth(L1)
    http-request auth unless auth_ok

userlist L2
    user johnhttps insecure-password doedoe

listen webproxiesHttps 0.0.0.0:3129
   mode tcp
   bind *:3129
   balance roundrobin
   server proxy01 [proxy_ip_1]:[port] check
   server proxy02 [proxy_ip_2]:[port] check
   acl auth_ok_https http_auth(L2)
   http-request auth unless auth_ok_https
```

Note: [proxy_ip_1]:[port] and [proxy_ip_2]:[port] are usually the real IPs.

Any idea welcome!

Thanks

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, "it doesn't work that way." Specifically, you can't tell HAProxy, simultaneously, to treat the connections as opaque conduits for TCP connections *and* impose HTTP basic auth. These are not HTTP connections, from HAProxy's perspective.  Using `mode http` on 3129, configuring `bind :3129 ssl ...` and `server ... ssl` will probably be necessary, terminating TLS on HAProxy and establishing a new TLS connection to the back-end. This plus `mode http` should work since the client will presumably still use HTTP `CONNECT` over TLS transport.